# UFT does not keep data when accessing library (qfl file)

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I'm running an UFT test.

My test uses a data sheet (in the `Action` code):

```
DataTable.ImportSheet "C:\UFT-DATA\something.xlsx","someotherthing","Global"
```

I use this datasheet to populate some variables:

```
Dim Yay
Yay=DataTable.Value("Yay","Global")
```

Then I'm using this variable in a function:

```
doescoolstuff(Yay)
```

This function is defined in a .qfl library which uses the comparison feature:

```
FileContent("blabla.pdf").Check CheckPoint("blabla.pdf")
```

And in this checkpoint I have:

```
DataTable("Yay", dtGlobalSheet)
```

The problem is... I don't know how this dtGlobalSheet should be populated. As a matter of fact, my variable in the `Action` section isn't taken into account. In debug mode, it just disappears from the `Data` tab.

Does anyone have a tip?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dtGlobalSheet` is uft constant which contains the sheet ID for the global sheet. `DataTable("Yay", dtGlobalSheet)` and `DataTable("Yay", "Global")` are the same thing - I've seen it that the `dtGlobalSheet` can fail and sometimes struggles to be referenced when passed around. If it's behaving weird, stick with `"Global"` as the sheet name identifier.....  Is that the info your answer? - Other than that i'm struggling to see what your error is and might need some more info :-)